# Adjustable Andros-like stem for 31.8 handlebar

Tags: stem, folding-bicycle

I have used the [Tern Andros stem system](https://buy.ternbicycles.com/products/andros-stem) and got one with it well.
[image]
Recently I acquired a Riese and Muller folding bike, which has an adjustment system which (for me) is less comfortable.  It puts the handlebar too close to me, so I would like it lower and further away.

I would therefore like to fit an Andros-like system to my Riese and Muller bike.

However, the Tern Andros system fits a 25.4mm handlebar, whereas the Riese and Muller system fits 31.8mm (oversize) bars.

(The Riese and Muller handlebar fixing system cannot be swapped out and fits an oversize tube, so I can't just buy the Andros system and swap handlebars. - thanks for the suggestion)

My question is:

- Is there something like the Andros adjustment system pictured, but for 31.8mm handlebars?
- Or perhaps, is there a handlebar design that takes a standard oversize tube fitting and which brings the control surfaces *down* and/or *forward* (away from me) by a few centimetres?

Comment: Can't you change the handlebar too?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  The issue is the fitting on the Riese and Muller stem.  It's a non-removable proprietary clamp which takes a handlebar directly, and it's set up for an oversize handlebar.

Comment: You want the bars closer to you? Or further away?

Comment: Interesting - - this is exactly what I need to do with my folder too.  Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @MaplePanda Further away.  Thanks for the question; I edited the text to make this clear.

Comment: @Jim I think you could use some MTB riser bars flipped upside down.

Comment: @MaplePanda Thanks, but would that not put the handlebars at a poor angle?  They'd be angled away from me rather than towards me.  It seems to me this would likely be quite uncomfortable, or at least, no more comfortable than cycling with my arms slightly more bent than I would like, as they are now --- which is not sustainable for long periods.

Comment: @Jim Try to find the least angled bars you can find. Something like this: https://www.amazon.ca/UPANBIKE-Mountain-Bicycle-Handlebar-φ31-8mm/dp/B071P6C9YV A lot of MTB bars have backsweep, it feels perfectly comfortable. It actually suits the natural angle of your arms better.

Comment: I have the opposition problem :-) Provided the bike doesn't already have it, it looks like the only realistic alternative is to swap the Comfort stem for the Sport stem for ~US$200 https://postimg.cc/hXNrWBbC